# Typing Error, List dinamic per List Movie

Tags: flutter, dart

I want it to return this: <List>, but I don't know how to type it, that I actually return that with the VideoMapper

```
ERROR:
A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be returned from the method 'getYoutubeVideosById' because it has a return type of 'Future<List<Video>>'.dartreturn_of_invalid_type
```

```
CODE:
@override
  Future<List<Video>> getYoutubeVideosById(int movieId) async {
    final response = await dio.get('/movie/$movieId/videos');
    print(response.data.toString());
    final moviedbVideosReponse = MoviedbVideosResponse.fromJson(response.data);

    final videos = moviedbVideosReponse.results
        .where((element) => element.site == 'YouTube')
        .take(1)
        .map((e) => VideoMapper.moviedbVideoToEntity(e))
        .toList();
    return videos;
  }
```

Comment: Does `VideoMapper.moviedbVideoToEntity` return a `Video` object?